# Интеграция WebBrowser в WinForms и работа с его содержимым

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Есть сайт, на котором расположена большая матрица из картинок. К примеру карта. 
На сайт я захожу с помощью контрола [webbrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx), размещённого на форме.

Можно ли как-то с помощью винформс сделать так, что бы на этих картинках располагался некий текст? Допустим номер каждой картинки. Или например поверх некоторой части сайта натянуть некоторую сетку, с такими же картинками, но что бы клик по картинке на сетке соответствовал клику по такой же картинке на сайте.

Comment: Не ленитесь ясно формулировать задачу, скорее получите помощь

Comment: Что именно не понятно? Я поясню.

Comment: После правки стало понятнее, вы не находите? До правки, понять вашу задачу было непросто.

Comment: Ну если понятно, дайте тогда совет пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если модификация а-ля Dynamic HTML посредством javascript вам подходит, то можно вот так:

```
HtmlElement headElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptElement = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement domScriptElement = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElement.DomElement;

domScriptElement.text = "function applyChanges(){/*пишите сюда javascript модификации страницы*/}";

headElement.AppendChild(scriptElement);

//Запуск функции javascript
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("applyChanges");
```

Если нет возможности использовать javascript, попробуйте править страницу прямо из C#:

```
//Предположим, вы нашли картинку, на которой надо сделать надпись.
HtmlElement image = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("image1")[0];
//Создаём надпись.
HtmlElement tag = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("div");
tag.SetStyleAttribute("display", "inline");
tag.SetStyleAttribute("position", "relative");
tag.SetStyleAttribute("left", "-100px");
tag.SetStyleAttribute("top", "-100px");
tag.innerText = "надпись1";
image.AppendChild(tag);
```

Comment: ничего не понятно ;(

Comment: Что именно не понятно? Я вам дал готовый кусок кода для вашей формы, который вставит в web-страницу javascript, который может сделать со страницей всё, что вы захотите.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не знаком с js. Возможно это и идеальное решение, не спорю. Можно ли как-то реализовать мою задачу, как я предложил в вопросе, с "натягиванием сетки" ?

Comment: Натягивание сетки будет гораздо труднее реализовать. Можно, конечно. Я бы на вашем месте, если нет сил разбираться с javascript, просто стал бы править DOM web-страницы приямо из C# кода.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можно ли как-то с Вами связаться отдельно?

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков Пишите сюда свой контакт, не знаю, не противоречит ли это правилам форума. Скажу сразу, за вас я код писать не буду :)

Comment: И не нужно) просто парочки мудрых советов хватит) icq 593259558